# Compare 2 dataframes, assign labels and split rows in Pandas/Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes consisting expected_orders and actual_orders details.

Input data:

[image: input]

I want to create a label field in both dataframe and split the rows based on following criteria:

- Sort by country, product and date
- Group both data frames by country and product
- In both data frames, for each group if row's date and qty are matching then assign label same actual date/ same expected date
- If qty is matching but dates are different then assign labels (earlier expected date/ later expected date) and (earlier actual date/ later actual date)
- If qty is not an exact match but there are qty values remaining in other data frame of that group then split the row with greater qty value df to 2 rows: matching (less) qty value and remaining value
- Repeat steps unless all rows have labels
- If no quantity is remaining from other group then assign label no actual date or no expected date

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

I am trying to do this with nested loops but with millions of rows this is quite slow.

```
for key, exp in expected_grouped:
  act = actual_grouped.get_group(key)
  ...
  for i, outerrow in enumerate(exp.itertuples()):
    for j, innerrow in enumerate(act.itertuples()):
      if: ...
      elif: ...
```

Is there any better and faster way to do this? Any suggestions for improvement would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As I understand your problem, the output depends a lot on given sequence, especially, the requirement to split and match. In that case row by row iteration of both dataframes is the only way. If it had not been that way, joins could have solved your problem. Do you not have any solution or are you looking to improve a working solution?

Comment: And there are some use cases you need to clear e.g. if first row in expected_orders has qty "200", then it is split as "100" and "100". First "100" has label "same actual date". What happens with second "100" part? "no actual date" or it gets matched with next entry with date "2022-01-08" in actual_orders?

Comment: The other use case is if first row in expected_orders has qty "200" and second row in actual_orders has date "2022-01-07", then when qty "200" is split as "100" and "100", then does the second "100" match with actual_orders record with date "2022-01-07" or do the two "2022-01-07" records in expected and actual orders with same qty take precedence?

Comment: I do have the solution and it is through iteration only. If in a group (country and product), after split we have remaining qty in other data frame then we will continue to perform same actions recursively until one of the data frame's qty is exhausted or both are matched. That is, again check if there is any qty and if it is not exact match then split and assign labels based on date

Answer (score 2):

You can use `label_orders` function below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from typing import Tuple


def label_orders(
    expected_orders: pd.DataFrame,
    actual_orders: pd.DataFrame,
) -> Tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
    if not (actual_orders["qty"] > 0).all():
        raise AssertionError("qty must be positive")
    if not (expected_orders["qty"] > 0).all():
        raise AssertionError("qty must be positive")

    orders_matched = match_orders(expected_orders, actual_orders)
    del expected_orders, actual_orders

    orders_matched["label"] = label_orders_matched(orders_matched)
    expected_labeled = filter_and_relabel_expected(orders_matched)
    actual_labeled = filter_and_relabel_actual(orders_matched)
    return expected_labeled, actual_labeled


def match_orders(expected: pd.DataFrame, actual: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    expected.sort_values(by=["country", "product", "expecteddate"], inplace=True)
    actual.sort_values(by=["country", "product", "actualdate"], inplace=True)

    expected["cumulative_qty"] = expected.groupby(["country", "product"]).agg(
        {"qty": np.cumsum}
    )
    expected.drop(columns="qty", inplace=True)
    actual["cumulative_qty"] = actual.groupby(["country", "product"]).agg(
        {"qty": np.cumsum}
    )
    actual.drop(columns="qty", inplace=True)
    orders_matched = pd.merge_ordered(
        actual,
        expected,
        on=["country", "product", "cumulative_qty"],
        how="outer",
    )
    del expected, actual

    orders_matched.sort_values(
        by=["country", "product", "cumulative_qty"], inplace=True
    )
    orders_matched["qty"] = orders_matched["cumulative_qty"] - orders_matched.groupby(
        ["country", "product"], sort=True
    )["cumulative_qty"].shift(1)
    is_first_in_group = orders_matched["qty"].isna()
    orders_matched["qty"][is_first_in_group] = orders_matched["cumulative_qty"][
        is_first_in_group
    ]
    orders_matched.drop(columns="cumulative_qty", inplace=True)
    orders_matched["qty"] = orders_matched["qty"].astype(int)

    orders_matched["actualdate"] = orders_matched.groupby(
        ["country", "product"], sort=True
    )["actualdate"].fillna(method="backfill")
    orders_matched["expecteddate"] = orders_matched.groupby(
        ["country", "product"], sort=True
    )["expecteddate"].fillna(method="backfill")

    return orders_matched


def label_matched_orders(orders_matched: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    labels = pd.Series(index=orders_matched.index, name="label", data="")
    labels.loc[orders_matched["actualdate"].isna()] = "no actual date"
    labels.loc[orders_matched["expecteddate"].isna()] = "no expected date"

    both_dates_present_mask = (~orders_matched["actualdate"].isna()) & (
        ~orders_matched["actualdate"].isna()
    )
    labels.loc[
        both_dates_present_mask
        & (orders_matched["actualdate"] < orders_matched["expecteddate"])
    ] = "actual before expected"
    labels.loc[
        both_dates_present_mask
        & (orders_matched["actualdate"] == orders_matched["expecteddate"])
    ] = "same date"
    labels.loc[
        both_dates_present_mask
        & (orders_matched["actualdate"] > orders_matched["expecteddate"])
    ] = "expected before actual"

    return labels


def filter_and_relabel_actual(orders_matched: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    actual_labeled = orders_matched.loc[
        ~orders_matched["actualdate"].isna(),
        ["country", "product", "actualdate", "qty", "label"],
    ].copy()
    actual_labeled["label"] = actual_labeled["label"].map(
        {
            "actual before expected": "later expected date",
            "same date": "same expected date",
            "expected before actual": "earlier expected date",
            "no expected date": "no expected date",
            "no actual date": "no actual date",
        }
    )
    return actual_labeled


def filter_and_relabel_expected(orders_matched: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    expected_labeled = orders_matched.loc[
        ~orders_matched["expecteddate"].isna(),
        ["country", "product", "expecteddate", "qty", "label"],
    ].copy()
    expected_labeled["label"] = expected_labeled["label"].map(
        {
            "actual before expected": "earlier actual date",
            "same date": "same actual date",
            "expected before actual": "later actual date",
            "no actual date": "no actual date",
            "no expected date": "no expected date",
        }
    )
    return expected_labeled
```

#### Explanation

Except for order matching and splitting part, the code is straightforward. But match & split part is a little tricky.

Let's use this example: in single `(country, product)` group after ordering by date there are expected_orders with qty `[100, 300]` and actual_orders with qty `[300, 100, 200]`. We can draw it like this:

```
Expected qty:   |-100-|-------300-------|
Actual qty:     |-------300-------|-100-|----200----|
```

(each order qty is drawn as a segment. Segment length is equal to order's qty. Segments are put on a line side-by-side, preserving the order).

Let's draw vertical line through each segment's endpoint to divide segments into parts of same lengths:

```
Vertical lines: |-----|-----------|-----|-----------|
Expected split: |-100-|----200----|-100-|           .
Actual split:   |-100-|----200----|-100-|----200----|
```

Using this figure, we can split orders into parts of same qty:

- expected `[100, 300] -> [100, 200, 100]`
- actual `[300, 100, 200] -> [100, 200, 100, 200]`

This logic is implemented in `match_orders()` function:

- list positions of vertical lines, separately for actual_orders and expected_orders by evaluating cumulative sums of qty among group.
- unite line positions of actual and expected by merging on actual and expected dataframes on group key and cumulative qty
- evaluate segments' lengths by taking difference between consecutive cumulative sums
- fill `actualdate` and `expectdate` for order parts

```py
def match_orders(expected: pd.DataFrame, actual: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    expected.sort_values(by=["country", "product", "expecteddate"], inplace=True)
    actual.sort_values(by=["country", "product", "actualdate"], inplace=True)

    expected["cumulative_qty"] = expected.groupby(["country", "product"]).agg(
        {"qty": np.cumsum}
    )
    expected.drop(columns="qty", inplace=True)
    actual["cumulative_qty"] = actual.groupby(["country", "product"]).agg(
        {"qty": np.cumsum}
    )
    actual.drop(columns="qty", inplace=True)

    orders_matched = pd.merge_ordered(
        actual,
        expected,
        on=["country", "product", "cumulative_qty"],
        how="outer",
    )
    del expected, actual

    orders_matched.sort_values(
        by=["country", "product", "cumulative_qty"], inplace=True
    )
    orders_matched["qty"] = orders_matched["cumulative_qty"] - orders_matched.groupby(
        ["country", "product"], sort=True
    )["cumulative_qty"].shift(1)
    is_first_in_group = orders_matched["qty"].isna()
    orders_matched["qty"][is_first_in_group] = orders_matched["cumulative_qty"][
        is_first_in_group
    ]
    orders_matched.drop(columns="cumulative_qty", inplace=True)
    orders_matched["qty"] = orders_matched["qty"].astype(int)

    orders_matched["actualdate"] = orders_matched.groupby(
        ["country", "product"], sort=True
    )["actualdate"].fillna(method="backfill")
    orders_matched["expecteddate"] = orders_matched.groupby(
        ["country", "product"], sort=True
    )["expecteddate"].fillna(method="backfill")

    return orders_matched
```

#### Single group example

##### Input:

```py
expected = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country": "US",
        "product": "Pen",
        "expecteddate": ["2022-01-05", "2022-01-07"],
        "qty": [300, 500],
    }
)
print(expected)
actual = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country": "US",
        "product": "Pen",
        "actualdate": ["2022-01-05", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-09"],
        "qty": [100, 800, 200],
    }
)
print(actual)
expected_labeled, actual_labeled = label_orders(
    expected_orders=expected, actual_orders=actual
)
print(expected_labeled)
print(actual_labeled)
```

##### Output

```
  country product expecteddate  qty
0      US     Pen   2022-01-05  300
1      US     Pen   2022-01-07  500

  country product  actualdate  qty
0      US     Pen  2022-01-05  100
1      US     Pen  2022-01-08  800
2      US     Pen  2022-01-09  200

  country product expecteddate  qty              label
0      US     Pen   2022-01-05  100   same actual date
1      US     Pen   2022-01-05  200  later actual date
2      US     Pen   2022-01-07  500  later actual date

  country product  actualdate  qty                  label
0      US     Pen  2022-01-05  100     same expected date
1      US     Pen  2022-01-08  200  earlier expected date
2      US     Pen  2022-01-08  500  earlier expected date
3      US     Pen  2022-01-08  100       no expected date
4      US     Pen  2022-01-09  200       no expected date
```

#### Multi-group example:

##### Input:

```py
expected = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country": ["US"] * 2 + ["Germany"] + ["Japan"] * 5,
        "product": ["Pen"] * 2 + ["Paper"] + ["Crayon"] * 5,
        "expecteddate": ["2022-01-05", "2022-01-07"]
        + ["2021-12-31"]
        + ["2022-03-15", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-16", "2022-03-17", "2022-03-17"],
        "qty": [100, 100, 2000, 100, 50, 150, 250, 50],
    }
)
print(expected)
actual = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country": ["US"] * 3 + ["Japan"] * 4,
        "product": ["Pen"] * 3 + ["Crayon"] * 4,
        "actualdate": ["2022-01-05", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-08"]
        + ["2022-03-15", "2022-03-15", "2022-03-19", "2022-03-19"],
        "qty": [100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 150, 250],
    }
)
print(actual)

expected_labeled, actual_labeled = label_orders(
    expected_orders=expected, actual_orders=actual
)
print(expected_labeled)
print(actual_labeled)
```

##### Output:

```
   country product expecteddate   qty
0       US     Pen   2022-01-05   100
1       US     Pen   2022-01-07   100
2  Germany   Paper   2021-12-31  2000
3    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-15   100
4    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-16    50
5    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-16   150
6    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-17   250
7    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-17    50

  country product  actualdate  qty
0      US     Pen  2022-01-05  100
1      US     Pen  2022-01-08  100
2      US     Pen  2022-01-08  100
3   Japan  Crayon  2022-03-15  100
4   Japan  Crayon  2022-03-15   50
5   Japan  Crayon  2022-03-19  150
6   Japan  Crayon  2022-03-19  250

   country product expecteddate   qty                label
0  Germany   Paper   2021-12-31  2000       no actual date
1    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-15   100     same actual date
2    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-16    50  earlier actual date
3    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-16   150    later actual date
4    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-17   250    later actual date
5    Japan  Crayon   2022-03-17    50       no actual date
6       US     Pen   2022-01-05   100     same actual date
7       US     Pen   2022-01-07   100    later actual date

  country product  actualdate  qty                  label
1   Japan  Crayon  2022-03-15  100     same expected date
2   Japan  Crayon  2022-03-15   50    later expected date
3   Japan  Crayon  2022-03-19  150  earlier expected date
4   Japan  Crayon  2022-03-19  250  earlier expected date
6      US     Pen  2022-01-05  100     same expected date
7      US     Pen  2022-01-08  100  earlier expected date
8      US     Pen  2022-01-08  100       no expected date
```

Comment: Great contribution! I think there would be value in combining our solutions.  That would likely provide a full solution.  Pandas doesn't work on a large data scale but would be an excellent choice for the function that is passed to the `mapPartions` as that wold run on the executor and would be a good place to use pandas.

Comment: I am agree with you, for big data I would definitely go with spark. But for several millions of rows - as the author says - I would first try plain pandas and if it proves to be too slow - optimize it by rewriting with spark.

Comment: I am not sure starting with Pandas first is a good first solution by default.  If the intent is the data is never going to grow and you are a Panada fan then it makes sense to select Pandas.  If the data is never going to grow and your a fan of Pyspark then it makes sense to select Pyspark.  If you think the data will grow beyond the space of one computer you should start with Pyspark.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely close to the solution you are speaking about. It uses group by and then aggregates the data in `mapPartitions`. This is fragile code that is written as a proof of concept.  It's not **the answer** but should inspire a complete answer.

I freely admit I didn't complete the logic for partial match but I think with more time it could be fixed up to complete the anwer.

The results of the below query could be rejoin to the relevant table to complete the correct labeling.
The key elements in the proof of concept:

- Union the data to collect it into one datafram
- group the data and use `collect_list` to gather the grouped information
- when using collect list `struct` is a key player to capture the data
- use `groupBy.rdd.mapPartitions` to spread the work over your executors to maximize parallel work
- in your partition function return an array of the tuples (to allow you to split records)
  -`explode` the records to create the records you need
- use `._1` to pull the information back out of the tuples

.

```
#create data
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
data = [
("us"    ,"Pen"    ,   100 ,"2022-01-05"  ),
("us"    ,"Pen"    ,   100 ,"2022-01-07"  ),
("Japan"    ,"Paper"    ,    100,"2022-03-15" ),
("Japan"    ,"Paper"    ,   200 ,"2022-03-16" ),
("Japan"    ,"Paper"    ,   300 ,"2022-03-17" ),
("Germany"    ,"Crayon"    ,   2000 ,"2021-12-31"  ),
]
columns = ["Country","Product","expected_qty","expected_date"]
columns = ["Country","Product","qty","date"]

df_expected = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df_expected  = df_expected.withColumn( "table", F.lit("expected") )

data = [
("us"    ,"Pen"    ,   100 ,"2022-01-05"  ),
("us"    ,"Pen"    ,   100 ,"2022-01-08"  ),
("Japan"    ,"Paper"    ,    100,"2022-03-15" ),
("Japan"    ,"Paper"    ,   50 ,"2022-03-16" ),
("Japan"    ,"Paper"    ,   400 ,"2022-03-17" ),
]
columns = ["Country","Product","actual_qty","actual_date"]
columns = ["Country","Product","qty","date"]

df_actuals = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df_actuals = df_actuals.withColumn( "table", F.lit("actuals") )

#join data with Union
groupBy = df_expected.union(df_actuals).groupby( "Country", "Product")\
.agg(
 F.array_sort( #sorts by all 3 fields so date data is sorted
  F.collect_list(
   F.struct(
    F.col("table").alias("table"),
    F.col("qty").alias("qty"),
    F.col("date").alias("date")
   )
  )
 ).alias("myStruct"),
)
#all python in a mapPartition function. Runs on Executors
 def f(partitionData): 
 for row in partitionData:
  data_map = {"expected":{},"actuals":{}}
  result = []
  #fix data into usable format to pull out matches
  for i in range(0, len(row.myStruct ) ):
    entry = data_map[row.myStruct[i].table]
    qty = row.myStruct[i].qty
    if qty in entry:
      entry[qty].append( row.myStruct[i].date )
    else:
      entry[qty] = [row.myStruct[i].date ]
  for qty in data_map["expected"]:
    if( qty in data_map["actuals"]):
     while len( data_map["expected"][qty]) > 0 and len(data_map["actuals"][qty]) >0:
      #add more complex logic here to get better lables I just do a lazy label that could be corrected in a later join.
      result.append( ( qty,  data_map["expected"][qty].pop(), data_map["actuals"][qty].pop(), "match" ))
  # Sort data by date to complete paritals and remove empty lists
  exp_date = [ item for item in sorted( data_map["expected"].items(), key=lambda x: x[1]) if len(item[1]) > 0 ]
  actuals_date = [ item for item in sorted( data_map["actuals"].items(), key=lambda x: x[1]) if len(item[1]) > 0 ]
  if len(exp_date) > 0:# this needs to be worked into a `while` loop to handle more data but shows the potential of how this could work
   j = 0;
   left_over = exp_date[j][0];
   left_over_date = exp_date[j][1][0]
   if len(actuals_date) == 0:
    while len(exp_date) > 0:
     item = exp_date.pop(0)
     result.append( (item[0], item[1][0], None, "no actuals"))
   else:
    for i in range( 0, len(actuals_date)):
     if left_over >= actuals_date[i][0]:
      result.append( (actuals_date[i][0],  left_over_date, actuals_date[i][1][0], "partial"))
      left_over = left_over - actuals_date[i][0]
     else:
      result.append( (left_over, left_over_date, actuals_date[i][1][0]  , "partial"))
      left_over = 0
  else:
   while len(actuals_date) > 0:
    item = actuals_date.pop(0)
    result.append( (item[0], None, item[0][0], "no expected"))
   
  
  #handle no matching dates here
  yield [row.Country, row.Product, result ] 


groupBy.rdd.mapPartitions(f).toDF(["Country","Product","Records"])\
.select( F.col("*"), F.explode(F.col("Records")).alias("record") )\
.select( F.col("Country"), F.col("Product"), F.col("record._1").alias("qty"),F.col("record._2").alias("expected_date"),F.col("record._3").alias("actual_date"),F.col("record._4").alias("label") )\
.show(100,False)
+-------+-------+----+-------------+-----------+----------+
|Country|Product|qty |expected_date|actual_date|label     |
+-------+-------+----+-------------+-----------+----------+
|Japan  |Paper  |100 |2022-03-15   |2022-03-15 |match     |
|Japan  |Paper  |50  |2022-03-16   |2022-03-16 |partial   |
|Japan  |Paper  |150 |2022-03-16   |2022-03-17 |partial   |
|Germany|Crayon |2000|2021-12-31   |null       |no actuals|
|us     |Pen    |100 |2022-01-07   |2022-01-08 |match     |
|us     |Pen    |100 |2022-01-05   |2022-01-05 |match     |
+-------+-------+----+-------------+-----------+----------+
```